# Looking for a string

Tags: sql

My Data set has 10 columns with 10,000 rows.

the columns have IDs. Example:

```
       A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
Row1 - 1a,2a,null,3a,null,null,null,null,null,null
Row2 - 1b,2b,3b,4b,5b,6b,7b,8b,null,null
Row3 - 1c,2c,3c,4c,null,5c,null,null,null,null
```

I would like to add column, where the latest non-null value is picked up.

How do I go about doing this?

Example of required output:

```
       A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,Desired_output
Row1 - 1a,2a,null,3a,null,null,null,null,null,null,3a
Row2 - 1b,2b,3b,4b,5b,6b,7b,8b,null,null,8b
Row3 - 1c,2c,3c,4c,null,5c,null,null,null,null,5c
```

Comment: It is very bad db design to store values as csv in a column

Comment: `coalesce(j, i, h, ..., a)`

Comment: Do you want the solution in R or SQL?

Comment: R is case sensitive, the proper name for nulls is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that you use in SQL is `coalesce()`:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j,
       coalesce(j, i, h, g, f, e, d, c, b, a) as desired_output
from t;
```